# Image manipulation with JQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, image-manipulation

I want to do some kind of image editor, after I upload more images I make a list with all the thumbnails!

After, I want to be able to click on one thumb and rotate, duplicate, drag and drop (to change positions of the images), and delete the image.  I want all the images to be in a php array. If an image is deleted I want to delete the row from array too. If a image is drag-and-dropped I want to change the position in the array too.

Ok, after the user uploads all the images and modifies some of them, how can I make a DONE button to save the positions of the images?

I made all ready all this, i only need to know how i can save the list of images after i "edit" with jquery? i need a save button or something

For this small project how do you suggest I save the images? (to make a table in mysql and store the names of the images in the database depending on the session id? depending on the IP?)

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Way, waaay too all-encompassing question.

My suggestions:

- Get familiar with [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)
- Get familiar with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/), especially the drag & drop functionality
- Store images in a temp folder on disk

  - Write a caching mechanism around it that'll clear the folder of unused images in regular intervals
  - Hashes can help to retrieve images from cache
- Store state in a session

Do some work on this and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Yes, thanks! About caching and hashes I need to know more! can delete, rotate, drag and drop, But When i refresh the page is the same! i need to make changes in the server side too! u think this could help me: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCache ??

Comment: @robertdd Make a new, more focussed question about this! Nobody can help you with the level of detail you gave.

Comment: i allready done this.. upload, list the images, rotate, delete, drag and drop, but only in jquery, after i refresh the page, the php array loops again and display all the images! i need a save button to do what?

Comment: @robertdd Again, with this level of detail, what do you expect as answer? Show some code! (In that new question of yours.)

Comment: drag and drop question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664982/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-and-php ! about rotate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664923/image-rotate-with-jquery-and-php